# jQuery, Sortabtable: I want to drag at the center, but height is wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following draggable list items structure:

```
<ul id="dadCol_0" class="dad-list ui-sortable">
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl1" style="position: relative;">1</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl2" style="position: relative;">2</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl3" style="position: relative;">3</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl4" style="position: relative;">4</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl5" style="position: relative;">5</li>
</ul>
```

the jQuery:

```
dad_list.sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.dad-list',
    containment: '#containment',
    items: 'li.dad-item',
    cursorAt: {
        top: Math.round($(this).outerHeight() / 2)
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        serializedads();
    }       
});
```

this all is OK, but it looks .outerHeight() is 0, the dragged item stucks to the top. I need the height / 2 position.

Comment: your `$(this).outerHeight()` returns the height of your _ul_, not of the dragged _li_

Comment: and how to return with the dragged li? The heights can be different

Comment: Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7jPnr/2/): at the start of the drag, recalculate the cursorAt value. I have found this not to be very reliable though...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cursorAt: function(ui){
    top: Math.round($(ui.item).outerHeight() / 2)
}
```